# How to sort by relevance on Flickr? (Not using Flickr API Module)

Tags: javascript, api, flickr

The Flickr API defaults to search for the most recent photos. I want my API to sort by most relevant photos first. I tried adding "&sort=relevance" to my url and while the API still returns it is not sorting by relevance.

Here is my base code:

```
function getFlickr(query) {
var proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
var url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=' + query + '&sort=relevance&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: proxy + url,
    // dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        renderFlickrResults(response, query);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, e) {
        console.log(status, e);
    }
});
}
```

What am I missing? Thank you for your help!